# Nginx is not rewriting URLs ending in .php

Tags: redirect, nginx

Trying to redirect all requests from `http://domain.com/subfolder/` to `http://new-domain.com/subfolder/`

With the configuration I have right now everything is working fine but if the URL is pointing to a php file, the redirect is not made, instead is trying to access the file from `domain.com`

Nginx configuration for `domain.com` is:

```
    server {
            server_name  domain.com;
            return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
            root /var/www/vhosts/domain.com;

            # Redirect that's now working for php file:
            location /subfolder {
                    return 301 http://new-domain.com$request_uri;
            }

            index index.php;

            # Here are the default Wordpress nginx configuration files included
            include /etc/nginx/global/restrictions.conf;

            # Additional rules go here.

            # Only include one of the files below.
            include /etc/nginx/global/wp-multisite.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/global/wordfence.conf;
    }
```

Wordpress configurations included are the one from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

And the nginx.conf is looking like this:

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
            worker_connections 768;
            # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

            limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=2r/s;

            ##
            # Basic Settings
            ##

            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;
            client_max_body_size 9M;
            # server_tokens off;

            # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
            # server_name_in_redirect off;

            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;

            ##
            # SSL Settings
            ##

            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

            ##
            # Logging Settings
            ##

            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

            ##
            # Gzip Settings
            ##

            gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";

            # gzip_vary on;
            # gzip_proxied any;
            # gzip_comp_level 6;
            # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            # gzip_http_version 1.1;
            # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

            index              index.php index.html index.htm;
            upstream php {
                    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            }

            ##
            # Virtual Host Configs
            ##

            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

So the question is, why is nginx trying to serve the php file from `domain.com` instead of redirecting? Is because of the `upstram` configuration from `nginx.conf`?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!